# Exchange Web Services authorization without username/password

Tags: c#, authentication, exchangewebservices

I am working on a project which uses the Exchange Web Services API on behalf of users. While I can easily authenticate using username, domain and password, I would have to store these credentials in plain text on a server. Is there any way to store an authorization token of some sort, such that I do not need to store usernames and passwords?

Alternatively, I am considering implementing a very rudimentary symmetric encryption scheme, wherein the user's password will be encrypted using some static knowledge of the user. I.e. the simplest case, a hash of their username. This way, the credentials are at least not in plain text, requiring them to reverse engineer the application.

Comment: Have you come up with a solution on this?

Comment: I have still not found a solution, and I have actually ditched the project because of this. There may be a way to do this using Server to Server authorization: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa579435(v=exchg.140).aspx 
It does seem to be the case that EWS does not have great support for limited trust, or for applications not to require username and passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Resurrecting an old question here, but this is a solution:

Set up a service account and give it impersonation rights.

MSDN articles:

[How to: Configure impersonation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn722376(v=exchg.150).aspx)

[Working with impersonation by using the EWS Managed API 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633680(v=exchg.80).aspx)